# How can I retrieve a packet payload as a bytearray in Scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

I have some code that attempts to extract packet payload as a bytearray, by getting the string value from the packet (I believe it returns a bytestring, as a string). How can I just get the raw payload as a bytearray?

```
packets = rdpcap(pcapFile)
p = packets[0]

if TCP in p:
    pdata = str(p[TCP].payload)
elif Raw in p:
    pdata = str(p[Raw].load)
elif TLS in p:
    pdata = str(p[TLS].msg)
else:
    pdata = ""
```

When I print pdata, it looks like this

```
b'\x17\x03\x01\x00 a\xb9j\x17#\xb9uX\xdf\xe3\x08\xe0\xbc\xc3\xce\xa2=\xda\xc9\xd7\x1d7*\xad\xc9Y\xcer1\xdc\xb2\xd1\x17\x03\x01\x00
```

But it seems that, that is a string, not a bytestring, ad pdata[0] returns `'b'`

How can I get the "payload" as `bytes` or `bytearray`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont use `str()` function bytes object

change `str(p[TCP].payload)` to `p[TCP].payload.decode()`

or if you just want it as bytes, just return the `p[TCP].payload` it self

## Update

`bytes(p[TCP].payload)`

Comment: p[TCP].payload has no decode attribute, and p[TCP].payload returns a <class 'scapy_ssl_tls.ssl_tls.SSL'>

Comment: The answer before the update is hysterical. `decode()` will try to parse raw bytes as UTF8 (or ASCII on Py2). This will likely get you an Encoding error.